# android better start-up performance

Tags: android, performance

Im looking for a way to improve class boot-up time or at least the preceived time.

I've read that in the JDK  an application's splash page can be displayed even before the JVM (in this case dalvik VM) starts thus giving a perceived performance increase.    How can this be achieved in Android ?

Comment: May I ask what you're doing while starting up? The possibilities to improve your performance depend on the issues of the delay. About splash screens: you *can* use them in Android, but usually there are better solutions depending on your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "splash page can be displayed even before the JVM starts thus giving a
>   perceived performance increase"

Not true. The splash page is displayed before your application's Activity get displayed. This is implemented in the Android Activity Manager Service and Window Manager Service.

In terms of speed up boot up performance, the only is under application's control is to do only necessary initialization in `onCreate()` and `onStart()`

Comment: Yeah. AFAIK, Java App side has Splash screen classes while on Android side doesn't this thing but, there's a way.

Answer (score 0):

design by performance and pre-load.

```
welcome_activity.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/welcome" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

WelcomeActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome_activity);

    AlphaAnimation alphaAnim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f);
    alphaAnim.setDuration(DURATION_TIME);
    alphaAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    alphaAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // startMainActivity();
            // finish();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.image_welcome).startAnimation(alphaAnim);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that in the JDK an application's splash page can be displayed even before the JVM starts thus giving a perceived performance increase.

Firstly, Android doesn't execute code in a JVM. At build time, the bytecode produced is Dalvik and so Android uses a DVM. Sorry to be pedantic but it's useful to know that.

Second, I'd recommend you read [Splash Screens Are Evil, Don't Use Them!](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/) Not everybody will agree with the sentiments expressed by the author but I personally do.

My opinion is that a splash screen which provides nothing but a pretty picture actually increases perceived lag in performance as there is no indication to the user that anything is actually happening or when the app is going to appear.

If anything, if you need to perform some long-running operation when the app is started, a ProgressDialog with text telling the user what is happening should suffice. Similar to a download or installer dialog "Performing Step 1 of 8..." for example.